# Не работает Wine

Tags: linux, kali-linux, wine

Хочу опробовать программу Wine для Linux. Говорят, что это эмулятор Windows, с помощью него можно запускать .exe на Linux. И как раз при попытке запуска exe файла, Wine выдаёт это:

```
0024:err:seh:start_debugger Couldn't start debugger L"winedbg --auto 32 52" (2)
Read the Wine Developers Guide on how to set up winedbg or another debugger
```

В гугле по этому поводу есть много информации, но она пустая - не помогает решить проблему.
Использую Kali Linux 2020.4, запускаю от root пользователя.

Comment: запускать можно, но зачем это делать с под рута? да ещё и отлдачик запускать? попробуйте для начала запустить обычный блокнот

Comment: Ну и добавить к тому, что сказал @KoVadim, можно, что .Net возможно заработает и без особых напрягов с Wine через mono.

Comment: @0andriy моно без винформс, а дотнет приложение не зависимое от винформс это редкость.

Comment: `Говорят, что это эмулятор Windows` погугли как расшифровывается само название проекта.

Comment: @eri, ждём проги на `WinUI`.